# Using vDSP.convertElements with vDSP.RoundingMode

Tags: swift, accelerate-framework

I am trying to round all elements in the vector using new static function [`convertElements`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3240896-convertelements) from Accelerate framework.

Sadly i don't know how to use it.

Here is what i tried:

```
let a: [Double] = [10.6, 20, 30.8, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
var b = [Int](repeating: 0, count: a.count)
var round: vDSP.RoundingMode = vDSP.RoundingMode.towardNearestInteger
vDSP.convertElements(of: a, to: &b, rounding: round)
```

This code throws error:

> error: ambiguous reference to static method 'convertElements(of:to:rounding:)'
>   vDSP.convertElements(of: a, to: &b, rounding: vDSP.RoundingMode.towardNearestInteger)

Any idea how to use this function?

Seems like setting value of [`vDSP.RoundingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/roundingmode) type is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong type for the `to:` array.  It needs to be `[Int32]`, not `[Int]`.

Change:

```
var b = [Int](repeating: 0, count: a.count)
```

to:

```
var b = [Int32](repeating: 0, count: a.count)
```

In the [link you provided](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3240896-convertelements), the definition of the function is:

> ```
> static func convertElements<U, V>(of source: U, to destination: inout V,
>     rounding: vDSP.RoundingMode) where U : AccelerateBuffer,
>     V : AccelerateMutableBuffer, U.Element == Double, V.Element == Int32
> ```

Notice that `V.Element` is `Int32`.

As noted by @MartinR in the comments, other types are possible including `Int8`, `UInt8`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, and `UInt32`.  All of the calls are detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp-snv).

Comment: It can also be an array of Int16 or Int8. All possible combinations can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp-snv.